# Euclidean distance between data sets in R using rdist from "fields" package

Tags: r, matrix, euclidean-distance

I am using `rdist` to compute Euclidean distances between a matrix and itself:

```
> m = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,3),nrow=3, ncol=3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    4
[3,]    1    2    3
library(fields)
> rdist(m)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 1e-10 1e+00 1e-10
[2,] 1e+00 1e-10 1e+00
[3,] 1e-10 1e+00 1e-10
```

What confuses me is that I think it should have 0s on the diagonal (surely the distance of a vector to itself is 0?), and for the same reason it should have 0s where it compares the first and third row. The value that I see instead (1e-10) looks way to big to be numerical noise. What's going wrong?

EDIT: `rdist` is from the package `fields`.

Comment: `rdist` is not a base R function as far as I can tell. Please tell us which package you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `1e-10` is simply `1*10^-10` which is `0.0000000001`, so numericaly very close to `0` (as it is a result of square rooting, so the actual error in the computation is of row of magnitude `1e-20`). Is it "too big"? Well, library is written in fortran, and is focused on **speed**, so it is quite acceptable. If you analyze the exact code, you will find out how it is computed:

```
# fields, Tools for spatial data
# Copyright 2004-2011, Institute for Mathematics Applied Geosciences
# University Corporation for Atmospheric Research
# Licensed under the GPL -- www.gpl.org/licenses/gpl.html
"rdist" <- function(x1, x2) {
    if (!is.matrix(x1)) 
        x1 <- as.matrix(x1)
    if (missing(x2)) 
        x2 <- x1
    if (!is.matrix(x2)) 
        x2 <- as.matrix(x2)
    d <- ncol(x1)
    n1 <- nrow(x1)
    n2 <- nrow(x2)
    par <- c(1/2, 0)
    temp <- .Fortran("radbas", nd = as.integer(d), x1 = as.double(x1), 
        n1 = as.integer(n1), x2 = as.double(x2), n2 = as.integer(n2), 
        par = as.double(par), k = as.double(rep(0, n1 * n2)))$k
    return(matrix(temp, ncol = n2, nrow = n1))
}
```

And the exact answer is hidden in the fortran files (in `radfun.f` called from `radbas.f`), where you can find the line

```
if( dtemp.lt.1e-20) dtemp =1e-20
```

which treats small (even 0) values as `1e-20`, which after taking square root results in `1e-10`. It seems that the motivation was to speed up the process by using logarithm of the value (as a result, square rooting is simply dividing by 2), which of course is not defined for `0`.

Comment: No need to be so condescending. Had forgotten about the square root, now the size of the error makes more sense.

Comment: condescending? I simply addressed all potential issues, as it was not clear (for me), which part is causing the problem. Removed the redundant information after clarification.

Comment: added the more precise answer based on fortran source

Comment: I see nothing condescending in this answer, either